# The ring-buffer don't read the correct data

Tags: java, buffer

I started to work on a project to generate sounds at different frenquencies. In that aim, I'm using 3 objects:

- a generator to create the sinusoidal signal and generate sound packets numbered (with a simple integer ID), sampled at 44100 Hz and using an "Observable" pattern.
- a "ring-buffer" which is "Observer" of the generator. It will store the packets in an array (not a list) used as the buffer
- a reader to read the sound data into the ring-buffer

In the `Main` class, I created a break (`Thread.sleep`) between the creation of the buffer and the creation of the reader. It allow me to fill a bit the ring-buffer before the lecture starts (and I also wanted to see what will happen...)

The problem is about the ring buffer (the code is below). If the break is short enough to not fillfull the ring-buffer when the lecture starts, everything seems more or less ok.
But, if my buffer is filled (and in many other unexplained cases), my sound have many parasites. And if I analyse the result of the ID of the read packets, here is what I get :

```
Buffer.load - packet ID : 63 - buffer pos. = 62
Buffer.load - packet ID : 64 - buffer pos. = 63
Buffer.load - packet ID : 65 - buffer pos. = 64
Buffer.read - packet ID : 65 - buffer pos. = 2
Buffer.read - packet ID : 65 - buffer pos. = 3
Buffer.read - packet ID : 65 - buffer pos. = 4
Buffer.read - packet ID : 65 - buffer pos. = 5
```

The read method send always the same packet ID, whatever the position of the reader into the buffer. However, the load method seems to work correctly and load the following ID in following positions.

```
public class Buffer2 implements Observer {

    private Object[] buffer;
    /*
     * important note about the buffer : 
     * It is an array and not a list.
     * So, it will be impossible to shift on the left or on the right the elements
     * (a method like deleteFirst or similar doesn't exsits for arrays)
     * in case of lecture (then suppression) or adding of en element.
     * So, I'll use three variables : one to know the lecture position in the buffer
     * one for the writing position
     * a last one to know the volume data into the buffer.
     */
    private int inBuffer, bufferSize, first, last;

    public Buffer2 (int bufferSize) {
        buffer = new Object[bufferSize];
        inBuffer=0;
        last=0;
        this.bufferSize=bufferSize;
    }

    public synchronized byte[] read () {
        while (inBuffer==0) {
            try {
                wait();
                System.out.println("Buffer.read = null");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // See the method "load()" for the explanation of the next line
        first=(first+1)%bufferSize;
        inBuffer--;
        /*
         * This method awake the threads which were sleeping because of the load() method
         * when the buffer is full 
         */
        notifyAll();
        Object[] temp = (Object[]) buffer[first];
        System.out.println("Buffer.read - packet ID : "+(int)temp[0]+" - buffer pos. = "+first);
        return (byte[]) temp[1];
    }

    public synchronized void load (Object[] data) {
        while (inBuffer==bufferSize) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Buffer.load : full !");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /*
         * Method to calculate the position to add the new value : 
         * Ex : buffer size = 10 and we just read the 3rd position
         * (3+1)%10 = 4 => the new value will be added in the 4th position of the array
         * Ex2 : if the position was 9 :
         * (9+1)%10=0 => the value would be added at the position 0 of the array.
         */
        last = (last+1)%bufferSize;
        inBuffer++;
        System.out.println("Buffer.load - packet ID : "+(int)data[0]+" - buffer pos. = "+last);
        buffer[last]=data;
        /*
         * Awake for all waiting threads locked
         * because the buffer was empty
         */
        notifyAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object obj) {
        if (observable instanceof Generator) {
            load((Object[]) obj);           
        }       
    }
}
```

---

What is wrong ? Thank you for all your answers.

After few tests and checks, I noticed few things :

- the `update()` method receive different values and call the `load()` method with those values. So, it seems it works as requested.
- just before altering the buffer with the instruction `buffer[last]=data;`, I checked if the data are those from the `update` method : yes, they are. So, it works.
- Just after having altered the buffer, I check the datas in the whole buffer (for the tests, I just used a buffer with 10 values). And here is the problem : all the values are the same, even if they were introduced earlier in the array. To say it in another way, when I load a new value in the array, all the values are modified and become equals to this last value.

Thanks to Thomas for the tips to identify a bit more precisely the problem, but, I still can't solve it.

Who will help me more ?

Thank you to all.

Comment: Side note: It looks like your buffer is an array of object arrays, so why isn't the type `Object[][]`? That would let you get rid of the casts and make the code much clearer.

Comment: In a first time, I didn't used the "ID" but only the raw data. I added the ID to try to understand the problem. But you are right, I should modify my code and change the type to Object[ ][ ]

Comment: I didn't thoroughly analzye your code (that would be your job anyways, e.g. by stepping through with a debugger) but is there any chance that the data array being passed to `load()` is reused instead of replaced? Since you don't create a defensive copy but just do `buffer[last]=data;` you might alter the array in the buffer from the outside after you've added it. That might cause all elements to actually be the same instance which has id 65.

Comment: Frankly, this question has nothing to do with `javasound`.

Comment: "is there any chance that the data array being passed to `load()` is reused instead of replaced?" => it seems not but it is an interesting trail. However, why does it could happens ? I use the `load()` only when I am noticed by the observer pattern. "you might alter the array in the buffer from the outside after you've added it" => what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found and fixed the problem, helped with the tips of Thomas. Indeed, I had a side effet when I received my data via the `update()` method.
The packet received is an `Object[2]` the 2 objects in it are another `Object[]` for the header and a `byte[]` for the datas themselves.

So, I have to read each value of each array of this packet to write them in a "single use" object (`Object[] packet = new Object[2]`).

So, the code for the `update()` method fixed is :

```
    @Override
    public synchronized void update(Observable observable, Object obj) {
        if (observable instanceof Generator) {
            // A packet contain a header (header) and datas (data)
            Object[] packet = new Object[2];

                /*
             * The header contain 3 datas : 
             * [0] ID
             * [1] The number of byes in the array of bytes
             * [2] the AudioFormat
             */
            Object[] header = new Object[3];
            header[0]= ((Object[]) ((Object[]) obj)[0])[0];
            header[1]= ((Object[]) ((Object[]) obj)[0])[1];
            header[2]= ((Object[]) ((Object[]) obj)[0])[2];
            // I reconstruct the hehader in the position [0] in the packet
            packet[0]=header;


            byte[] data = new byte[(int) header[1]*4];
            for (int i=0; i< data.length ; i++) {
                /*
                 * Reading each byte in the [i] position of the bytes[]
                 * This array of bytes is in the position [1] of the array which is the Object[] obj
                 */
                data[i] =  ((byte[]) ((Object[]) obj)[1])[i];
            }
            // I reconstruct the data in the position [1] of the packet
            packet[1]=data;
            // I feed the load() method with the packet
            load(packet);
        }       
    }
```

I expect my answer will help someone else. Have a good day.